# how to create two divs shapes to overlay each other

Tags: html, css

How can I create two separate divs with css shapes to overlap each other? I need to be able to load content to the particular divs as well.

The shape is a circle then behind is a rounded rectangle. I need to be able to place custom img to fit within the circle and to place small copy and images into the rectangle.

Any suggestions? Right now, I just have all the content in one div.

```
<div class="box">
<img src="images/profile_image.png" /><br />
First Last <br />Chicago, IL
<br /></div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
 margin: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #58585B;
 text-align:left;
 font-size:12px;
 width:200px;
 border-radius:10px;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task, I would use 2 divs and have the circle with a z-index value so that it will overlap the rectangle div.  Make your border-radius size fairly large so that the circle div will accurately resemble that shape.

Try using this code:

CSS:

```
#circle {
background-color:#333333;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius:25px;
z-index:10;
margin-left:25px;

}

#rectangle {
width:100px;
height:50px;
border-radius:10px;
background-color:#AAAAAA;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="rectangle">
<div id="circle">
</div>
</div>
```

here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LynchJustRules/yPwzW/3)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way for me to add a paragraph or imgs inside the shape itself? I tried to place the p tag between one of the shapes but it's not self containing in a either shape.

Comment: I think so.  Give me a few mins and I'll set up another fiddle.

Comment: Here is the updated jfiddle to what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/LynchJustRules/Q7xEE/

Comment: Forgot to mention that I don't recommend putting text inside the shape that you wish to put images since if you put a <p> tag inside the shape, it is going to push down the images themselves.  However if you do take this approach, you have to be very precise with how you position your images.  Hope this all helps!